# Kerasにおけるy_pred,y_trueのサイズについて

Tags: python, keras

Kerasを用いて入力60個，出力60個の回帰問題に取り組んでいます．
カスタム損失関数を作成する際にy_true,y_predのサイズがわからず処理できません．
batch sizeは128で教師データを10000個，その中で8000個を訓練データに，2000個をテストデータにしています．

Answer (score 0):

バッチサイズが128で、出力次元が60であれば、サイズは[128,60]ではないでしょうか？
試しにカスタム損失関数の中で、print(y_true.shape)のようなことを行って確かめられたりしないでしょうか？